# Phonegap upload to asp net webserver - No response

Tags: asp.net, cordova

this is my javascript code :

```
var fileURL = "file://" + mFileListURL[0].fullPath;
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "recFile";
var imagefilename = Number(new Date()) + ".jpg";
options.fileName = imagefilename;
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";    
var params = new Object();      
options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURL,"http://mywebserver/UploadFoto.asmx/SaveImage",
                function(r) {
                    alert("It's OK!");
                    alert("Response = " + r.response);

                }, function(error) {
                    alert("An error has occurred: Code = "
                            + error.code);
                }, options);
```

and this server side code:

```
        [WebMethod]
        [GenerateScriptType(typeof(String))]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public String SaveImage()
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
                foreach (string key in files)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile file = files[key];
                    string fileName = file.FileName;
                    if (fileName != null && fileName != "")
                    {                        
                        String fileStored = System.IO.Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("~/public/"), fileName);                           
                        file.SaveAs(fileStored);                       
                    }
                }
            }            
            return "Filestored OK";
        }
```

Now, image upload is done but I get no returned string, no response from server, no error code. I used Json response also but nothing (image is upload, no response, no string returned).
What's wrong?

Thanks. IngD

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function(r) 
{
  alert("It's OK!");
  alert("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WebMethod Must be static

```
[WebMethod]
        [GenerateScriptType(typeof(String))]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public static String SaveImage()
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
                foreach (string key in files)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile file = files[key];
                    string fileName = file.FileName;
                    if (fileName != null && fileName != "")
                    {                        
                        String fileStored = System.IO.Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("~/public/"), fileName);                           
                        file.SaveAs(fileStored);                       
                    }
                }
            }            
            return "Filestored OK";
        }
```

Comment: Could you explain why it should be?